# rails jquery-ui autocomplete is not returning anything

Tags: html, ruby, jquery-ui, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-5

I was able to return the list of predefined ingredients earlier but now i havn't gotten it to work at all. Was wondering if I could get some help please. When I type into the page it does not suggest any autocompletions at all. Thank you!

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord

belongs_to :user
validates :name,  presence: true

def ingredient_name
    self.try(:name)
end

def ingredient_name=(name)
    self.ingredient = Ingredient.find_by_name(name) if name.present?
end
```

HTML

```
<div class="field">
<%= form.label :ingredient_name %>
<%= form.text_field :ingredient_name %>
</div>
```

application.jss

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
```

application.scss

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
```

pages.coffee

```
jQuery ->
    $('#ingredient_name').autocomplete
        source: ['pepperoni', 'sausage', 'bacon', 'pineapple']
```

Comment: Is that the real indentation in `pages.coffee` or an artifact of posting your question?

Comment: I tried to get it to matchup with this example video. https://youtu.be/M7yhPlIehFA?t=3m22s

Comment: Indent the `source: ...` line so that you're calling `autocomplete` with an argument. Paste both versions into ["TRY COFFEESCRIPT"](http://coffeescript.org/#try:) and look at the JavaScript to see the difference.

Comment: I have edited in the indented version of the coffee file but still not working :(

Comment: You'll need to be a little more specific as to what "not working" means. Anything in the browser's console? Are you using TurboLinks? Does the autocompleter get bound? Have you attempted to debug this in the browser?

Comment: right, so when i load up the webpage, everything works fine. And I try to type an ingredient but it does not give any "autocomplete" suggestions. Everything else works fine. It's very frustrating because it was working this morning. I have basically just followed along the video I sent you earlier

Comment: Are you using TurboLinks? What's changed since this morning? Are you sure you have an `id="ingredient_name"` element in your HTML? Any errors in the JavaScript console? Does it work if you manually `$('#ingredient_name').autocomplete({ source: ['pepperoni', 'sausage', 'bacon', 'pineapple'] })` in the JavaScript console?

Comment: I made a ton of changes this morning that I didn't like so I reverted back to right before I added the autocomplete. this app does have Turbolinks. I'm sorry but i'm not sure how to manually enter code into JavaScript console. I'm just doing this semester long project for a class and am new to web developing.

Comment: I'm gonna revert to the beginning one more time, give it one more shot if not give up. So annoying because I got it working this morning.

Comment: If you're using TurboLinks then you want to bind things using `$(document).on('turbo links:load', -> ...)` rather than `$(document).ready(...)` (AKA `jQuery(-> ...)`). Your browser should have "developer tools" somewhere, that menu should let you open a JavaScript console which will display JavaScript errors and let run bits of JavaScript directly. You need to learn how to use these tools if you're going to develop anything that happens client-side.

Comment: Finally got it working! I just need to tweak the "source". I currently have it predfined but would like to search for the current ingredient database. Basically return @ingredients = current_user.ingredients

Comment: You could do it through AJAX or, if the list is small, embed it directly in the page with `<%= j ... %>` or as a JSON-encoded array.

Comment: Thank you so much! Got it working and doing as it should. Now I can just chill until the school semester ends and watch all anime all day 8)